# how to convert blob image to base64? base64 variable showing up as null

Tags: angular, typescript, get, base64, blob

I am trying to build a ui where if a button is pressed, a get request is made and an image is displayed. However, when trying to convert the image blob to base64, the base64 is showing up as null and I am not sure why. Below is my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  data:any
  image:any
  retrievedImage: any;
  base64Data: any;
  retrieveResonse: any;
  imageName:any;

  constructor(private imageData:imageService,
              private httpClient:HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    console.log(this.image)
   

    this.imageData.getImages().subscribe((results)=>{
     console.log(results)
     this.data = results
     })
  }
  
  getImage2() {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    //Make a call to Spring Boot to get the Image Bytes.
    this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8080/get/' + this.imageName,
      {responseType:'blob'})
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          this.retrieveResonse = res; //this is blob i think 
          reader.readAsDataURL(this.retrieveResonse)
          this.base64Data = reader.result;
          //this.base64Data = this.retrieveResonse.picByte;
          this.retrievedImage = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + this.base64Data;
          console.log(this.retrieveResonse)          
          console.log(this.base64Data)
          console.log(this.retrievedImage)
        }
      );
  }
}
```

Below is my HTML file:

```
<p>
    <mat-toolbar>
      <span>Image Repository</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
  </p>
<button mat-button style="position:relative; left: 5px; top:2px" (click)="getImage2()">Get an image </button>
<input #image type="text" style="position:relative;left:10px; top: 2.99px" [(ngModel)]="imageName">


<!-- <img *ngIf="image" style="position:relative;top:200px" [src]="image" alt="Place image title"> 
 -->
<div class="container row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <div *ngIf=retrievedImage>
          <img [src]="retrievedImage" style="position:relative;top:200px" >
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why is it that when the getimage2 method is called, the `this.base64Data` variable shows up as null when logged in the console? I would assume that the blob would be converted to base64 with this code?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to download the image

Use a generic `get` downloader:

```
  private download(url: string, params: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url, {
      reportProgress: true,
      observe: 'events',
      responseType: 'blob'
    });
  }
```

Call it from:

```
  onDownloadImage(): void {
    this.progress = 0;
    this.download(this.imageUrl, {}).subscribe((event: any) => {
      if (event.type === HttpEventType.DownloadProgress) {
        this.progress = Math.round((100 * event.loaded) / event.total);
        console.log('progress', event.loaded);
      } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        this.processReceivedBlob(event.body);
      }
    });
  }
```

once download is done process it

```
  private processReceivedBlob(blob: any) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      const dataUrl: any = reader.result;
      const base64 = dataUrl.split(',')[1];
      this.img.src = 'data:image/png;base64, ' + base64;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  }
```

in html:

```
<img [src]="img.src">
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-download-image?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)